# how to automatically run a script as root to mount a network share

Tags: mount, sudo

I'm rather new to *nix and have played a little with Ubuntu, Mint and now Elementary OS.

I'm doing a mistake but I don't understand where.

I'm mounting a network share via

```
sudo mount -t cifs //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/networkshare /mnt/local -o user=user,password=pass,uid=xxx,gid=xxx
```

the script is executable,
if I run the script in terminal all is ok,
it asks the password for root
and mount the share

but I would like it to be mounted automatically

I tried to put the command into `/etc/rc.local`
so the `#!/bin/bash` above it and the exit 0 below it are already there

I tried to put the command into Applications -> Startup Commands

I also tried to create a file.desktop into `/.local/share/applications`
(so, at least, it is easy to run)
as Exec I tried both

```
Exec=/path/filename.sh
```

and

```
Exec=sh /path/filename.sh
```

but none is working, none of the methods is asking me the root password

Surely I'm doing something wrong,
I did a google search but I've not been able to find some guide.
Can you drive me the right way ?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You want to run a script that does not need user interaction so there is absolutely no problem that it does not ask for the root password.

Actually the file `/etc/rc.local` is run with root user privileges, so it should work (without asking a password). However, the preferred method to mount filesystems automatically is to append them into the file `/etc/fstab`. There should be a line like this:

```
//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/networkshare /mnt/local cifs user=user,password=pass,uid=xxx,gid=xxx 0 0
```

Comment: This IS the *nix way to do a mount at boot ... but you might also want to add an alias for the IP address in you /etc/hosts file and then use the name that you created rather than the IP address in /etc/fstab ... this is assuming the the IP address does not constantly change. You also may want to look at the 'noauto' parameter for use in /etc/fstab if you have mounts that you only want to mount sometimes. 'noauto' just means that you need to issue a mount for that explicitly.